# What is the exact purpose of Azure cookie 'WAWebSiteSID'?

Tags: cookies, azure

My Azure websites sets a http session cookie named 'WAWebSiteSID'. I can't find any documentation on it. What is the exact purpose of this cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cookie is used by [Windows Azure WebSites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/) to identify which server instance has your request to go to.

Some more info on Windows Azure Web Sites can be found [here](http://ntotten.com/2012/06/07/10-things-about-windows-azure-web-sites/). Also a deep technical presentation can be browsed [here](http://www.slideshare.net/maartenba/windows-azure-web-sites-things-they-dont-teach-kids-in-school).

To fully understand (if you will), you will need to also understand [Application Request Routing module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).